# How to make pagination for Raw Query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I have written a raw Query form there I want to show in a large list. So for that I wanted to used pagination. But for raw query `->paginate(5);`

Here is sample raw query I've used:

```
public function managementReport(){
        $managementReport = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT members.name as name, 
                members.card_no as card_no, members.joining_date as joining_date,
                salary_terms.designation as designation, salary_terms.main_salary as main_salary,
                salary_terms.basic as basic,salary_terms.house_rent as house_rent,
                salary_terms.medical as medical,salary_terms.conveyance as conveyance,
                salary_terms.food as food,monthly_payrolls.days_on_month as days_on_month,
                monthly_payrolls.working_days as working_days,
                ((salary_terms.basic*monthly_payrolls.leave_without_pay)/monthly_payrolls.working_days) as absent,
                (salary_terms.main_salary - ((salary_terms.basic*monthly_payrolls.leave_without_pay)/monthly_payrolls.working_days)) 
                as gross_pay,monthly_payrolls.deduction,(salary_terms.main_salary -( ((salary_terms.basic*monthly_payrolls.leave_without_pay)/monthly_payrolls.working_days)+monthly_payrolls.deduction)) 
                as net_pay FROM members INNER JOIN salary_terms on members.id = salary_terms.member_id INNER JOIN 
                monthly_payrolls on salary_terms.id = monthly_payrolls.salary_term_id 
                WHERE salary_terms.is_management='1'"));
                return view("Report::management",compact('managementReport'));
        }
```

So How do i implement `paginate()` with raw query in laravel?

Comment: @marcin Nabialek sorry I couldn't find any helpful solution from the link you have marked as duplicate.

Comment: If you use raw query you need to manually paginate data, so you need to manually get data you need from database using `offset` in your query and pass those data you get into paginator

Answer (score 1):

Try to [create pagination manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) using DB data.

Maybe [this tutorial](http://psampaz.github.io/custom-data-pagination-with-laravel-5/) will be also helpful.

Comment: that throws an error , `Call to a member function paginate() on array`